# How to make mat-sort-header not all clickable

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table using the code below with sortable headers. However I also want to put a menu in the header for custom filtering. The problem is that because the whole header clickable and changes the 'sort' of the column, when i click on the menu it also sorts because the menu button is within the header.

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Borrower1">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> 
                    <div class="header">
                      Borrower1
                      <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #matMenuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" >
                        <mat-icon>filter_list</mat-icon>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                     <mat-menu #menu="matMenu"   >
                          <div (mouseleave)="matMenuTrigger.closeMenu()">
                            <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
                            <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
                            <button mat-menu-item>Item 3</button>
                            <button mat-menu-item>Item 4</button>
                            <button mat-menu-item>Item 5</button>
                          </div>
                        </mat-menu>     
                  </mat-header-cell>

                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Borrower1}} </mat-cell>

                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="_id">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> 
                    _id
                  </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element._id}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <a (click)="editDialog(element._id)" type="button">
                            <mat-icon class="icon">edit</mat-icon>
                    </a>
                  </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <a (click)="deletePost(element._id)" type="button">
                            <mat-icon class="icon">delete</mat-icon>
                    </a>
                  </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>   
                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
              </mat-table>
```

Is there a way to get around this

Answer (score 2):

Try taking everything in the header that you don't want triggering a sort, wrap it in a div, and put a click handler on it that calls $event.stopPropagation().

Comment: not working...
I have the same problem with mat-sort-header. I want to show MatMenu when click the header column to choose some condition after sorting, but i can't --> mat-sort-header starts sorting when i click...

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but seems that it is possible to set the `mat-sort-header` directive on a child element. So this seems to work:

```
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="sort-only-on-this" mat-sort-header>
            Borrower1
        </div>

        <button />
        ...
    </div>

</mat-header-cell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove mat-sort-header directive from header you don't want to be clickable (SORTABLE):

```
     <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="_id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                Id // NOT SORTABLE
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Id}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                Number // SORTABLE
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Number}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your menu inside a div and add (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" to your div like

```
<div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
   your menu....
</div>
```

Hope it solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine this (this is not according to your code but can help) :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="test" formGroupName="yourFormGroupName">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >
            <span [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu" class="cursor-pointer">Text</span>
            <span mat-sort-header arrowPosition="after"></span>
          </mat-header-cell>

          <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
            <!--some html-->
          </mat-menu>

          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let rowIndex = index">text</mat-cell>
          <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Actually the above html is not the html I am using (so I am not sure about it). The html I used is:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="test" formGroupName="yourFormGroupName">
          <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header class="cursor-pointer">
            <span [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="cursor-pointer">Text</span>
            <span arrowPosition="after"></span>
            <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
              <!--some html-->
            </mat-menu>
          </th>
          <td *matCellDef="let row; let rowIndex = index" mat-cell>text</td>
          <td *matFooterCellDef mat-footer-cell></td>
</ng-container>
```